# Algolia WordPress - how can I only index published posts and exclude all the drafts and private

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I have red the Algolia documentation (https://www.algolia.com/doc/) but I have never found any mention on how to exclude "draft" and "private" pages from being indexed. Moreover does anyone know how to do this for specific CPT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the default behavior of the official [Algolia for WordPress](https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/) extension is to only index the published post.

Custom Post types are handled by default but you may have to customize the attributes to index. You can find more details in the plugin documentation
https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/advanced-custom-fields.html
(example with ACF field but also works with standard meta field)